# Getting shiny app to react when timer counts down to zero

Tags: r, shiny

I have set up an timer as reactive values. values$total. It is designed to countdown to 2017-03-22 23:55:40 and when values$total is counted down to zero, it is supposed to add tally to values2$total. However, when I launch an app, values$total is frozen and is not moving. How can I get it to count down?

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  "Total:",
  textOutput("total", inline = TRUE),
  "Draft Count:",
  textOutput("draft_count", inline = TRUE),
  "Time:",
  textOutput("time",inline=TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(total = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-03-22 23:55:40")-now(),units="secs"))
  values2 <- reactiveValues(total = 0)

  observeEvent(values$total <= 0,{
    values2$total <- values2$total + 1
  })

  output$total <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    values$total
  })

  output$draft_count <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    values2$total
  })

  output$time <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    as.character(as.POSIXct(now()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
#values <- reactiveValues(total = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-03-22 23:55:40")-now(),units="secs"))
  val <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-03-22 23:55:40")-now(),units="secs")
  } )
  values2 <- reactiveValues(total = 0)

  observeEvent(values$total <= 0,{
    values2$total <- values2$total + 1
  })

  output$total <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    val()
  })

  output$draft_count <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    values2$total
  })

  output$time <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    as.character(as.POSIXct(now()))
  })
}
```